# Disk or USB or SD Storage

Tags: android

Assume that I have a 128GB Hard disk, and it is full of files (there is no space for free) and I delete all files in this Hard disk.

I know the files aren't REAL removed from the disk, they are just stored in another folder that I can't access.

But why do I still able to store other files to the disk after I clean up the disk?

Please explain details, thx a ton.

Comment: what are you refering to phone or pc ? . What do you mean by  *I know the files aren't Real removed from the disk, they are just stored in another folder that I can't access.*?

Comment: Erm... I found the reason... Thx for your time. 
https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001463.htm

Comment: If you wanted for pc why did you tag it with android ? . Only add relevant tags